# Mule how to map Json values from payload to flow variables

Tags: mule

I have a JDBC COnnector which retrieves values from the database and I have mapped them from object to JSON. Now I want to extract specific values from the json to flow variables. When I try to log #[message.payload], I get the full payload in the log which is in JSON format. However when I try to choose an attribute (eg. testattribute in json) #[message.payload.testattribute], I get mule expression error. How do I refer to the json values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once the payload is a JSON string, you can't extract anything from it anymore with an expression.

So either:

- use MEL to extract the values into flow variables prior to convert the payload into JSON,
- transform the JSON payload to either POJOs or Map/Lists, use MEL to extract the values into flow variables, and re-transform the payload back to JSON.

Answer (score 3):

If your requirement is to get the values from json data you can use a simple MEL expression like

```
#[json:<name of the node>]
```

For example if you have an sample json data like this

```
{
"token" : 123,
"id" : 456,
"email" : "abc@abc.com",
"status" : "Success"
}
```

and if you want get the id from the data just use the below simple MEL.

```
#[json:'id']
```

Answer (score 2):

Mule has JSON-to-Object transformer which can be used to get JSON elements.
For example if your JSON is following :-

```
{
  "token" : 123,
  "id" : 456,
  "email" : "abc@abc.com",
  "status" : "Success"
}
```

Now, to extract the elements, you need to use :-

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object" />
```

And then can extract like :- `#[message.payload.email]` or `#[message.payload.status]`

Answer (score 1):

Use components as follow

1. Object - String
2. Object - JSON

then u can directly extract using value using json expression as **#{json:email}**,
in below xml i have used the variable component to set the #{json:email} in "var1" flow variable for usability

Note: json expression is even available in studio version of 5.x

```
 <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
 <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
 <set-variable variableName="var1" value="#[json:email]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```